# TypeScript properly infer type in Array Access of a Union Type

Tags: typescript, union-types

While doing a relatively simple comparison for a custom `Option` interface, I've run into a type inference problem.

```js
export interface SelectiveRecommendation {
  sources: Array<string>;
  expression: string;
  recommendation: Array<string>;
}

export interface Option {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  description?: string;
  recommendation?: Array<string> | SelectiveRecommendation;
  children?: string;
  options?: Array<Option>;
}

/**
 * Compares two options/arrays of options for equality, considering nested options.
 *
 * @param options1 - The first option(s) to compare.
 * @param options2 - The second option(s) to compare.
 * @returns True if the arrays are equal, false otherwise.
 */
export const areOptionsEqual = (
  options1: Option | Option[],
  options2: Option | Option[],
): boolean => {
  // convert to array
  if (!Array.isArray(options1)) {
    options1 = [options1];
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(options2)) {
    options2 = [options2];
  }

  // Check if the lengths of the arrays are the same
  if (options1.length !== options2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // Check if there's any object in options1 that doesn't match the corresponding object in options2
  return options1.every((option1, index) => {
    const { name: name1, options: nestedOptions1 } = option1;
    const { name: name2, options: nestedOptions2 } = options2[index]; // ERROR HERE

    // Check if names don't match or one has nested 'options' while the other doesn't
    const areNestedOptionsEqual = !!nestedOptions1 === !!nestedOptions2;
    if (name1 !== name2 || !areNestedOptionsEqual) {
      return false; // Indicates a mismatch
    }

    // If either (& thus both) objects have nested 'options', recursively compare them
    if (nestedOptions1 && nestedOptions2) {
      return areOptionsEqual(nestedOptions1, nestedOptions2);
    }

    return true; // The options at this index are equal
  });
};
```

In the `.every` callback, this line

```js
const { name: name2, options: nestedOptions2 } = options2[index];
```

has the error

> `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'Option | Option[]'`

which is confusing me, since I have the guard to ensure both parameters are cast to type `Option[]`, as well as ensuring the arrays are the same length. Directly before the callback, both parameters are inferred as type `Option[]` (case in point, `options1.every` does not give any issues), but once inside the callback this is not the case.

I've tried

```js
const { name: name2, options: nestedOptions2 } = options2[index] as Option;
```

but I can't seem to safely access the elements inside `options2` through the index. My question is, why does TypeScript not recognize `options2` as an array? Do I have to create a new variable in order to do this?

Of course I'm able to get around it by adding

```js
if (!Array.isArray(options2)) {
  options2 = [options2]
}
```

at the beginning of the callback, but this is redundant.

Comment: Yes you need to create a new variable as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzDZQN).  Unfortunately TS doesn't know when the `every` callback will run and assumes pessimistically that any narrowing of closed-over values is no longer valid and thus resets it.  See [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for more information.  Does that fully address the question, or am I missing something?

Comment: The discussion link you posted perfectly answers my question. However, I feel that the duplicate has some subtle yet distinct differences; from what I can tell, it's more about understanding the fundamentals of union types and creating type guards (like I already have) versus understanding the difference brought up in the TS discussion of why `options2` would be `undefined` _in the callback_ after what I thought was a correct type guard.